# Organization Browser not rendering in Silverlight but HTML view works fine

Tags: organization-browser

I have installed SharePoint 2010 Standard Trial version as an in-built database for evaluation purposes. But I am having some issues getting the Organization Browser in My Sites working correctly.

When I click on the Organization tab the silverlight componet does not render. However if ckick on the words 'more information' the organization browser appears. I cannot navigate around the Organization Browser as when I move my mouse over people they just dissapear (e.g. nothing is clickable).

The HTML view of the Organization Browser works fine.

I am using IE9 and Silverlight v5. The Silverlight Organization Browser component works fine in Firefox.

As I am using an in-built database and this is only for evaluation purposes I am not sync-ing with AD. I have added a handful of user profiles manually via Central Admin.

Any help or advise is appreciated.
Thanks
N.

Comment: Which uathentication provider are you using?

Comment: Is it SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1?

Answer (score 1):

Check your browser is in compatibility mode.  That may fix the rendering issue. There are some subtle UI pieces which don't work perfectly in IE9, but work fine in IE8.

If you are using Claims authentication, there is a known issue with the organisation browser: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2643420 where the org. browser does not render correctly.

Service Pack 1 includes a couple of Silverlight Org. Browser fixes related to browsers and authentication, and using the back button, which may apply: http://www.etechplanet.com/blog/fixes-included-in-sharepoint-2010-service-pack-1-(sp1).aspx